# Passing values from parent component to child component in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to build an `angular` component which displays an image based on the src, width and height provided by the parent element.

This is my code:

**my-image-logo.component.html**

```
<img #imgDiv src="{{name}}" >
```

**my-image-logo.component.ts**

```
export class MyImageLogoComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() name;
    @Input() width = "100px";
    @Input() height = "100px";
    @ViewChild("imgDiv") imgDiv: ElementRef;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.imgDiv.nativeElement.setAttribute("width", this.width);
        this.imgDiv.nativeElement.setAttribute("height", this.height);
    }
}
```

**parent-component.html**

```
<app-my-image-logo [name]="userDetails.profilePic" [width]="'50px;'" [height]="'50px;'"></app-my-image-logo>
```

This works perfectly, but I was trying to not initialize the `width` and `height` in `ngOnInit`, instead use `ngStyle` as follows:

```
<img [ngStyle]="{'width': width, 'height': height}" src="{{name}}" >
```

But this is not working. I even tried the following, but even that doesn't work:

```
 <img width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" src="{{name}}" >
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, is this the right way to assign css styles for the components?

Comment: Your code should work with `<app-my-image-logo [width]="'50px'" [height]="'50px'" ...>` (without the `;`). See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k1ig4w).

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that, it is not working. On inspect I see that I get `width="0" height="0"`

Comment: Did you see the stackblitz? It is your original code (as shown in my previous comment), and it works.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks, yes it is working, I was trying with `[width]="width" [height]="height"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify attributes by doing this (in your child component):

```
<img [attr.width]="width" [attr.height]="height">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can share the parent's css file with a child with :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'lions',
    templateUrl: 'lions.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['lions.component.css', '../zoo.component.css']
})
```

(zoo is the parent, lion the child)

But in your case I would just set the child width and height to 100%, for exemple in lion.css :

```
:host() { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

( `:host()` means the root tag of your component )

Answer (score 0):

In your child component, you will have to change the HTML to

```
 <img [width]="width" [height]="height" [src]="name" >
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. On inspect I see that I get `width="0" height="0"`

Answer (score 0):

imgDiv might be undefined when we try to access in ngOnInit.
Try to do that inside ngAfterViewInit, but I am not sure whether we can change the width because the view already got drawn